# Implement Delayed job and cron job in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, cron, delayed-job

I had developed an application that has delayed job and cron job and I need to deploy it to Heroku. I realized my delayed job need Heroku adds-on, **"Heroku Scheduler Standard"** and it costs $34.50. 
1) Does that mean I need to buy that so that my delayed and cron job will run automatically?I wonder if delayed job and cron job can be done by using Heroku schedular then why we still need javan/whenever and collectiveidea/delayed_job? Can I use these in Heroku preferably in free condition?

2) My cron job does not worked in Heroku. How do I run my whenever gem in heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appear to be a couple of thoughts intermixed in your question. I'll do my best to separate them:

a) **DelayedJob on Heroku**

One way to process jobs queued in DelayedJob (i.e. records sitting in the delayed_jobs table in your database) is to run the following rake task:

```
$ rake jobs:work
```

On heroku, this rake task is commonly run via a 'worker' process.

By default for rails apps, your heroku app should already come with a slider for 'workers' (initially set to 0) that will run the rake task above. Merely sliding this to '1' (which will cost you around $34.00 per month) will launch the DelayedJob dequeue process in the background on a dedicated heroku instance, with your codebase, independent of your web dynos.

Note that DelayedJob does NOT require Heroku's "Scheduler" add-on.
Also note that heroku charges by hours of processing per month. So, if you slide your 'worker' to '1' for one hour a month, and then slide it back to '0' again when you're done, you will be paying far, far less than the ~$34 charge. There is a way to slide workers on and off programatically too.

b) **Cron on Heroku**

As it stands, managing your own, customized cron *file* is not possible on heroku or other cloud-based app service providers. Everything is ephemeral, and deployed files cannot be altered by you or your code.

Heroku's Scheduler is the appropriate add-on in this case to replace cron. You should be able to set tasks in your heroku scheduler to do what your cron tasks are currently doing.

Last I checked, heroku's scheduler was free (see: https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler), so I'm not sure why you state it is $34.50.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand more with your explanation.